# Change variable value if service method return value change in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a service method which returns bool value. am calling this method from controller. my need is, I want to update a variable value if this returning value change.

```
.controller('myCtrlController', ['$scope', 'myService',
    function ($scope, myService) {

    var update = function () { 
    var myVar = false;
    myService.getState() //here am calling service method, and i need  to change myVar = true if returning value changes.

if(myVar){calling another one method}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can $watch the value that your function is returning like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return myService.getState();
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal != oldVal){
        myVar = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question. Your code helps me to update the variable myVar. But based on this am calling another one method. Even myVar is assigned with true, i am unable to call this another method.

Comment: am I correct to think that you want to call a method if myVar changes its value?